# Placement of Previous and Next button in Setup

Tags: website-design

What is the best placement of a previous and a next button for a setup kind of scene?

We have a stepper but we decided to have both a stepper and the previous and next buttons.

Is it better to place them relative to the data? (so if a user adds data, the previous and the next button moves more to the bottom)

or

to place it in a fixed space (so no matter how many data a user adds, it stays in place in a sticky way)

Comment: Hey @llalamailaka, can you show a wireframe of the 'scene' you are talking about? It is hard to tell what your UI looks like and what users want to achieve with it (steppers, data, scene, adding data,...?).

Comment: @Ilalamailaka Please add more details about your situation, the problem you have and the kind of solutions you are looking for. Adding images will help getting better answers too.

Comment: The search on this site might bring up additional inspiration when using the terms "previous next"

Answer (score 1):

i think a simple wireframe could support your question to get a better idea of what you're intending for.

[image]

To have it sticky could be a bad UX when the users hasn't filled in all the fields but is already confronted with the next step.
I'd suggest to put it at the end of the content. See my screen attached.

I wouldn't use 'next' for the button wording. I'd suggest to write 'Proceed to final step' or 'Proceed to shipping details'.